# How to use AND and OR in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to get those records whose `date_last_copied` field is empty or less than the current date. I tried this, but it did not give me the desired result:

```
$tasks = $this->Control->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM
        `controls`
    WHERE
        `owner_id` = ".$user_id."
        AND `control_frequency_id` = ".CONTROL_FREQUENCY_DAILY."
        OR `date_last_copied` = ''
        OR `date_last_copied` < ".  strtotime(Date('Y-m-d'))."
");
```

Comment: PHP? mysqli_* or PDO functions?

Comment: Actually I am using Cakephp but query Syntax is Php

Comment: Should ideally be using their DB functions then: http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html

Comment: You probably should get the actual MySQL query working right before wrapping it, looks kinda convoluted in there. AND and OR are the correct syntax to use.

Comment: If i want to use this format of query then Can you see me query and point it where i am wrong?

Comment: Some suggestions:  be careful to include appropriate white space between statement elements... e.g. there should probably be a space before `AND`,,, **`"AND`** should probably be **`" AND`**.  Be aware of the order of precedence of `AND` and `OR`... `a AND (b OR c)` vs `(a AND b) OR c` .. use parens to override default. Beware of SQL injection vulnerabilities, including potentially unsafe values in SQL text, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current query looks something like this, I think. That is, find the records with the correct owner_id and frequency_id, where the date_last_copied is null or less than a certain date. Is that logic correct?

```
SELECT *
FROM controls
WHERE owner_id = ::owner_id::
    AND control_frequency_id = ::frequency_id::
    AND (
        date_last_copied IS NULL
        OR date_last_copied < ::date::
    )
```

But we should really be using the CakePHP query builder, rather than running raw SQL. This [article](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table) gives some details. If I were to take a stab at a solution, we'd want something like the following. But we ideally want someone from the CakePHP community to chime in here. EDIT: Note that this seems to be for CakePHP 3.0, only.

```
// Build the query
$query = TableRegistry::get('controls')
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'owner_id' => $ownerId,
        'control_frequency_id' => $frequencyId,
        'OR' => [
            ['date_last_copied IS' => null],
            ['date_last_copied <' => $date]
        ]
    ]);
// To make sure the query is what we wanted
debug($query);
// To get all the results of the query
foreach ($query as $control) {
    . . .
}
```

I'm suggesting this, rather than the raw SQL string you have above, because:

1. We can now leverage the ORM model of CakePHP.
2. We don't have to worry about SQL injection, which you're currently vulnerable to.

EDIT: OK, this is a guess at the syntax applicable for CakePHP 2.0... YMMV

```
$controls = $this->controls->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'owner_id' => $ownerId,
        'control_frequency_id' => $frequencyId,
        'OR' => [
            ['date_last_copied IS' => null],
            ['date_last_copied <' => $date]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Otherwise, we just use the raw query as a prepared statement:

```
$result = $this->getDataSource()->fetchAll("
    SELECT *
    FROM controls
    WHERE owner_id = ?
        AND control_frequency_id = ?
        AND (
            date_last_copied IS NULL
            OR date_last_copied < ?
        )",
    [$ownerId, $frequencyId, $date]
);
```

Comment: $tasks = TableRegistry::get('controls')
                ->find()
                ->where([
                        'owner_id' => $user_id,
                        'control_frequency_id' => CONTROL_FREQUENCY_DAILY,
                        'OR' => [
                            ['date_last_copied IS' => null],
                            ['date_last_copied <' => $current_date]
                        ]
                ]);

Comment: and get this error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in [/backup/websites/controls/app/Console/Command/Email2Shell.php, line 74]

Comment: What's on that line? :P It's very possible that I have a syntax error in there. Possibly replace the [] with array().

Comment: Is ORM for Cake 3 i am using Cake 2?

Comment: Could be... we may have to roll with this syntax instead: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: For this i use this one:

Comment: $tasks = $this->Control->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
    'owner_id' => $user_id,
      'Control.control_frequency_id' => CONTROL_FREQUENCY_DAILY,
                                                                              'OR' => array (                                                                                               array ('date_last_copied' => ""),
                                                                                            array('date_last_copied <' => $current_date)
  ) )));

Comment: But getting no result

Comment: hrm... not too sure, mate. Check your DB logs to see what query is being executed? That'll help use tune things a bit!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your whole logic but your final query statement should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `controls` WHERE (`owner_id` = <some owner_id>) 
AND (`control_frequency_id` = <some id value>)
AND (`date_last_copied` = '' OR 
     `date_last_copied` IS NULL OR 
     `date_last_copied` < CURDATE() )
```

Use parentheses carefully to match your logic.

Comment: Logic is that if current date is 2015-06-22 and in the field date is also same then do not get record and get only those records where field is empty if current date is 2015-06-23 and in the field date is 22-06-2015 then fetch both the records (empty one and filled one)

Comment: I think you can apply one of our answers in your code to see if you can get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Always specify the version of cakePHP you are using for your App.

This query should work fine in CakePHP 3.0 for SQL AND and OR.

```
$query = ModelName>find()
    ->where(['colunm' => 'condition'])
    ->orWhere(['colunm' => 'otherCondition'])
    ->andWhere([
        'colunm' => 'anotherContion',
        'view_count >' => 10
    ])
    ->orWhere(['colunm' => 'moreConditions']);
```